# Openni_tracker giving an error message "InitFromXml failed"?

Tags: ros, kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros indigo and kinect xbox.
When i run the "**rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker**", i was getting  error **InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!**
I followed the suggestion provided from this [link1](http://answers.ros.org/question/9737/openni_tracker-initfromxml-failed-cant-create-any-node-of-the-requested-type/) and [link2](http://answers.ros.org/question/130891/problems-with-openni_tracker-launching/)

Here is the sequence of commands that i followed.
I have installed `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-freenect-stack`
and `NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23`

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch &
roslaunch pr2_LookAround_pkg face_detector.rgbd.launch &
rosrun rviz rviz
```

I tried by adding license `sudo niLicense -l 0KOIk2JeIBYClPWVnMoRKn5cdY4=`  , but no luck.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239754/openni_tracker-giving-an-error-message-%22initfromxml-failed%22?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2017-01-10**:
hey buddy!!!! did u got u any help with openni_tracker and ros indigo???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can try this:sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev.
if it do not work :
$dpkg -l|grep openni   
  $rosdep install –from-path -s –reinstall
$env|grep ros

Do not forget to try the other usb port ！

---

Originally posted by [importSuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28481/importsuc/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0